# Disable input field with selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, disabled-input

Can you show me what I did do wrong here?

I would like to disable the input field when the Selection uses the second option (Treibstoffverbrauch in Liter).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="Kalkulationsart"]').on('change', function() {
    var eins = $(this).val();
    if (eins == "Kalkulation per Treibstoffverbrauch in Liter") {
      $('#VerbrauchinL').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#VerbrauchinL').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="KATitle">Kalkulationsart</p>
<select name="Kalkulationsart" id="Kalkulationsart" size="1" type="text">
  <option value="0">Kalkulation per Verbrauch/100km</option>
  <option value="others">Kalkulation per Treibstoffverbrauch in Liter</option>
</select>
<p id="KMTitle" for="VerbrauchinL">Kraftstoffverbrauch in Liter/100km</p>
<input type="number" name="Verbrauch in L" id="VerbrauchinL" onkeyup="TKPJ()">
```

Comment: `eins` is probably "0" or "others", try comparing `eins != "0"`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `$(this).val()` it returns the `value` attribute of the `option` element. So, you'd need to compare it with `0` or `others`.

See the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="Kalkulationsart"]').on('change', function() {
    var eins = $(this).val();
    console.log(eins);
    if (eins == "others") {
      $('#VerbrauchinL').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#VerbrauchinL').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="KATitle">Kalkulationsart</p>
<select name="Kalkulationsart" id="Kalkulationsart" size="1" type="text">
                     <option value="0">Kalkulation per Verbrauch/100km</option>
                     <option value="others">Kalkulation per Treibstoffverbrauch in Liter</option>

                    </select>

<p id="KMTitle" for="VerbrauchinL">Kraftstoffverbrauch in Liter/100km</p>
<input type="number" name="Verbrauch in L" id="VerbrauchinL" onkeyup="TKPJ()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` value is different (`others`) than what you comparing against.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Kalkulationsart').on('change', function() {
    $('#VerbrauchinL').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == "others");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="KATitle">Kalkulationsart</p>
<select name="Kalkulationsart" id="Kalkulationsart" size="1" type="text">
    <option value="0">Kalkulation per Verbrauch/100km</option>
    <option value="others">Kalkulation per Treibstoffverbrauch in Liter</option>
</select>

<p id="KMTitle" for="VerbrauchinL">Kraftstoffverbrauch in Liter/100km</p>
<input type="number" name="Verbrauch in L" id="VerbrauchinL" onkeyup="TKPJ()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, you need to check for the value in the checkbox (`others`) not the label used(`Kalkulation per Treibstoffverbrauch in Liter`).

I changed the way the attribute `disabled` is applied, we can toggle between `true` and `false`, to apply/unapply the attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="Kalkulationsart"]').on('change', function() {
    var eins = $(this).val();
    if (eins === "others") {
      $('#VerbrauchinL').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#VerbrauchinL').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="KATitle">Kalkulationsart</p>
<select name="Kalkulationsart" id="Kalkulationsart" size="1" type="text">
    <option value="0">Kalkulation per Verbrauch/100km</option>
    <option value="others">Kalkulation per Treibstoffverbrauch in Liter</option>
</select>
<p id="KMTitle" for="VerbrauchinL">Kraftstoffverbrauch in Liter/100km</p>
<input type="number" name="Verbrauch in L" id="VerbrauchinL" onkeyup="TKPJ()">
```

Comment: @Marcel Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

change "Kalkulation per Treibstoffverbrauch in Liter" to "others"
if you provide a value in the option val() gives the value